# asp.net c# gridview label value disappear when sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that contain label, the value of this label is assigned in code behind,
I enabled sorting in my gridview and when I click the header to sort the value of the label disappear but the other DataFields doesnt.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$Resources:mj.resource, req_category%>" SortExpression="category_id">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="category_id" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set EnableViewState="false" on the GridView or at the page level?

Are you using DataSourceControl (like SqlDataSource) to bind data to the GridView?
If so, you'd have to manually sort and bind data again in the Sorting event.